# Best way to bubble-wrap a greenhouse (adhesive?)

Tags: adhesive

I'd like to bubble-wrap my greenhouse.

What's the best kind of adhesive that meets these requirements?

```
(1) clear
(2) UV-resistant
(3) water-resistant
(4) cold and heat -resistant (all-weather)
(5) easy to remove and won't leave permanent marks, should I decided to remove it (this one is a bonus though)
```

Comment: "Best" is very subjective, but you've defined it, so you should be OK there. I do think you've got a near impossible list of requirements, though, but time will tell. What have you researched and rejected so far? Knowing this will help save others the time of recommending things you're not interested in. What kind of bubble wrap and what is the greenhouse made of - materials matter for adhesives. Finally, _why on Earth_ do you want to bubble wrap your greenhouse? Are you shipping it? Are tree limbs falling on it and breaking panels? I'm quite confused by the whole concept!

Comment: Rubber cement, not totally clear but will come off glass easily.

Comment: The closest thing I've come is an adhesive that's all-weather (Gorilla tape) but it's not clear and the rain seems to have washed it out. I need something that's clear.

Comment: Thanks @EdBeal I will look into it, even though it's not clear.